# Strange Protocol after unpacking received data

Tags: python, windows, sockets, ip, raw-sockets

Setting up the connection.

```
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
con = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
con.bind((HOST, 0))
con.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
con.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

Receiving data.

```
raw_data, addr = con.recvfrom(65536)
```

*raw_data :   \x45\x00\x00\x77\x00\x00\x40\x00\x40\x11\xb4\xc0\xc0\xa8\x02...*

Unpacking the raw data.

```
dest, src, proto = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])
```

*dest : \x45\x00\x00\x77\x00\x00*

*src :  \x40\x00\x40\x11\xb4\xc0*

*proto : 49320*

so my question is: is there an obvious mistake i am doing? what kind of ethertype (protocol) is 49320?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read your IPV4 packet definition from?
You're interpreting the data completely wrong!

It looks like you confused layer 2 (data link) and layer 3 (network layer) in the OSI model.  Sockets come in at layer 3.  Socket raw allows you to read the raw packets from layer 3.

Have a look at these links:

1. [IPv4 packet structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)
2. [List of IP Protocol Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)

So given this data:
`\x45\x00\x00\x77\x00\x00\x40\x00\x40\x11\xb4\xc0\xc0\xa8\x02...`

```
\x45     = Version (IPV4) + IHL (5 32bit ints = 20 bytes)
\x00     = DCSP (0 - best effort) + ECN (0 - Non ECN-Capable Transport, Non-ECT)
\x00\x77 = Total length (119 bytes)
\x00\x00 = Identification (0)
\x40\x00 = Flags (100 - MF - more fragments) + Fragment Offset (0)
\x40     = TTL (64 seconds)
\x11     = Protocol (UDP)
\xb4\xc0 = Header Checksum (0xb4c0)

Followed by source IP then dest IP. You haven't given these 
  fully so I can't decode them.
```

I hope this now makes sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#/media/File:Ethernet_Type_II_Frame_format.svg

Comment: @beary - that's an ethernet frame.  You're not reading ethernet packets but IP packets with socket raw.  Ethernet knows nothing about sockets that's 2 layers up!

Comment: @beary - yep!  Sorry I meant 1 layer up. Yes you confused the layers. I would be possible to read at the ethernet level if you need that low.  But I'm not sure how on windows.

Comment: one more question. what indicated to you that the given data does not include the mac destination and source / how did you see that my data is all layer 3 data? thanks again!

Comment: @beary - socket raw gives you the lowest layer of IP sockets which is layer 3.  So right away I knew what I should be decoding.