# What does socket.htons(proto) = 43200 mean?

Tags: sockets, ipv6, packet, ipv4, sniffer

While using socket.htons(proto) in my project, it gives a value of 43200. What does that mean?

I know socket.htons(0x0800) = 8 which means [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4). If 8 is for IPv4, what does 43200 mean?

Comment: You would have to provide the code and the context to determine what it means, include the value of `proto` that goes into `htons()`.

Answer (score 3):

43200 is A8C0 in hex. Since you're doing htons, and most hosts these days are little-endian, the bytes on the wire are probably c0, a8. Now in decimal, that is 192, 168, which is suspiciously like the first two bytes of a typical RFC1918 IP address, so my hunch is that you are interpreting the wrong bytes of some packet.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351229/strange-protocol-after-unpacking-received-data) is someone who managed to get the same value by mistake.

Answer (score -3):

You have noticed that "43200" is 86400/2 and 86400 is the number of seocnds in a day, hmm?